# Expected identifier or "(" on Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

So I am a total rookie at coding and I am trying to build my first app, i've got everything done but i keep getting this error message. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix is please? Thanks.

```
#import "JSSViewController.h"
#import "JSSMyScene.h"

@implementation JSSViewController
@import AVFoundation;
@end
@interface UIViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer * backgroundMusicPlayer;

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews;
{                                         (this is the error)!Expected identifier or '('
[super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

NSError *error;
NSURL * backgroundMusicURL = [[NSBundle mainBudle] URLForResource:@"background-music-aac" withExtension:@"caf"];
self.backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsofURL:backgroundMusicURL error:&error];
self.backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
[self.backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.backgroundMusicPlayer play];

// Configure the view.
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
if (!skView.scene) {
skView.showsFPS = YES;
skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

// Create and configure the scene.
SKScene * scene = [JSSMyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

// Present the scene.
[skView presentScene:scene];
}
}
@end
```

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: Yeah. First, the code is a total unreadable mess because of the complete lack of indentation. Secondly, this is not an Xcode question (Xcode is not the compiler nor the language, an as such, it's not quite relevant.)

Comment: It also helps to have the correct title - mixing up brackets could cause issues

Comment: The indentation isn't there because it was easier to see it this way rather than the way it was, it is there on my xcode version

Comment: And its on line 11 i think

Comment: Your comment re indentation and other things suggests try a simpler example first in a tutorial - even one without a GUI as you are making several errors and much easier to deal with one at a time

Comment: no error in @interface UIViewController ()  ?

Comment: nope, and after getting read of the ';', now i keep getting this error

Comment: - (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews    !expected ';' after method prototype
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

Comment: seriiously can anyone help me? this really sucks haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you should not have a ; after the method signature so you should have

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{ 
....
```

You also need to separate the implementation and th interface.

In the interface you have the ; and only the signature

```
@interface UIViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer * backgroundMusicPlayer;

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews;
@end
```

and then the code in an @implementation block

Comment: I tried that but then is tells me

Comment: that it expected ';' after method prototype

Comment: That caused a lot more issues, maybe i wasn't doing it right but i didn't work anything else?

Comment: im like really new to this haha so what do you mean by code in an @implementation block?

Comment: @user3126157 you need to start on an Objective C tutorial

Comment: ok thanks mark hopefully i can figure this out haha

Comment: Hey man I tried the tutorial and  it didnt help a whole lot, I'm still stuck and really just wanna figure this out, all i know is that after i did everything, it keeps saying"

Comment: expected ';' after method prototype